# What's the meaning of empty last line in jump list in Vim?

Tags: vim

I saw the bottom jump list in Vim (`ju` in normal mode) could be in 2 different forms as below. The current pos (> sign) points to empty line in the first output, but not the case for the second output. I am wondering how to enter such state of jump list separately and what's the effect on navigation?

```
  2 1 2 Some line in file
  1 2 2 Another line in file
>

  2 1 2 Some line in file
> 1 2 2 Another line in file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` shows your current position in the jumplist.

The empty line means that the cursor is currently not at a position in the jumplist.

No empty line means that you jumped to some position in the list.

Comment: thanks. As when `>` points to empty line, <C-o> will record the current position as the head of jumplist, is there a way to check the status of jump list directly (I mean whether the current head is empty). Also is there a way to insert empty line to jump list when navigation in the list?

Comment: The jumplist is read only: you can't modify it programmatically.